# Using a variable in a SELECT statement?

Tags: apex, soql

```
public static void handleCaseComment(CaseComment caseComment)
{
   User[] users = [SELECT LastName FROM User WHERE Id = caseComment.CreatedById LIMIT 1];
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
unexpected token: 'caseComment.CreatedById'
```

How do I use the value of the variable `caseComment.CreatedById` in a `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This way ?

```
public static void handleCaseComment(CaseComment caseComment)
{
   User[] users = [SELECT LastName FROM User WHERE Id = :caseComment.CreatedById LIMIT 1];
}
```

Variables are used with **`:`** (colon) as prefix.

Comment: I'd recommend highlighting the fact that he's missing the colon; it's easy to overlook.